# Foursquare Menu Endpoint returning error code 400 bad request

Tags: json, foursquare

I'm using Foursquare's API to retrieve the menu for each venue in an array of venues (venuesToSearch), but my code doesn't print anything to the console. By pasting the link into a JSON formatter, I was able to find out that I'm getting a 400 bad request error instead of a 200 as required by the if statement. [The official API endpoint](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/menu) says the link must be formatted like:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/VENUE_ID/menu

where VENUE_ID is a string containing the specific ID. Also, since it's a userless endpoint, users don't need to sign in with a Foursquare account to use the app; instead, I just need to supply a client ID and a client secret, both of which are declared as class level variables and appended to the URL using the &client_id string.

```
for venue in venuesToSearch {

        let urlString = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/
\(venue)/menu&client_id=\(CLIENT_ID)&client_secret=\(CLIENT_SECRET)&v=20150729"

if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: .allZeros, error: nil) {
                let json = JSON(data: data)
                if json["meta"]["code"].intValue == 200 {

/* Any code after this will not execute because of the error code 400 instead of 200 */
```

Am I formatting the URL wrong? Or is the reason I'm getting a 400 result something else entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct one is not "menu&" but "menu?", I suppose. Please try following URL:

```
let urlString = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/\(venue)/menu?client_id=\(CLIENT_ID)&client_secret=\(CLIENT_SECRET)&v=20150729"
```